# Is specific volume a function of temperature only (in liquids)?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, volume

As far as I know, you can take the equation  $pv=RT$ (with
$v$ being the specific volume) for ideal gases. But I had a question in a quiz asking about this, and the answer was "dependent on temperature only" (for liquids, which ain't exactly ideal gases). I just can't find the right equation to prove this.
What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide any additional information? The specific volume of liquids depends on pressure also (although to a lesser extent than gases), so the answer appears incorrect.

Comment: There appears to be a disconnect. The equation applies only to ideal gases and has nothing to do with liquids. Please describe the quiz question in its entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the schematised $p,V,T$ diagram of a non-ideal gas:

[image: Non-ideal gas p,V,T diagram]
[Image source.](https://www.google.com/search?q=pv%20diagram%20for%20no%20ideal%20gases&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&rlz=1I7DSGP_enGB473&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=nwK19bpZWCbJiM%253A%252CRJGOSZBEc9coSM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kSVNUVyxTxK21WLEToN0vQnaRhZUg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslf_ZwNfgAhU0tXEKHTmmCd0Q9QEwDHoECAQQCg&biw=1366&bih=625#imgrc=-7G_aguOFEBaFM:)

Left is the liquid area of the diagram. One can see that the volume has a small dependence on pressure (liquids are said to incompressible: $\frac{\partial V}{\partial p} \approx 0$) but has a stronger dependence on temperature.